# Comparing Hochschild (co)homology for algebras and coalgebras

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, cohomology, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Given a field $k$, an associative $k$-algebra $A$, and an $A$-bimodule $M$, one can define as the Hochschild homology and cohomology as the homology of the complexes
$$M\otimes A^{\otimes n}$$
and
$$\text{Hom}(A^{\otimes n},M)$$
respectively (with appropriate differentials)

One can similarly define Hochschild (co)homology for a coassociate coalgebra $C$ and a bicomodule by taking homology of the complexes
$$C^{\otimes n}\otimes M$$
and
$$\text{Hom}(M, C^{\otimes n})$$

Is it known how the algebra and coalgebra versions are related? In particular, given a Hopf algebra, do both approaches compute the same objects?

Answer (score 2):

We assume $A$ and $M$ are finite dimensional, and denote by $A*$ and $M*$ their respective duals. Denote by $HH_n$ and $CH_n$ the Hochschild homology of an algebra and a coalgebra respectively, and similarly for cohomology.  Then a fairly direct computation shows

$$HH_n(A,M)\cong CH_n(M*,A*)$$

and similarly for homology. If $A$ is a Hopf algebra, the two computation give the same object if $A$ is self dual and the bimodule and bicomodule structures on M are dual.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?